# Marshal.GetExceptionPointers and DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: c#, wpf, pinvoke

Good day. There is a `WPF application` + dumper (`MiniDumpWriteDump`). It is necessary at occurrence `UnhandledException` in application to create`minidump` and then to lay down application.

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnStartup(e);
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
      Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;
    }

[DllImport("Kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentThreadId", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern Int32 GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();

private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  var pointers = Marshal.GetExceptionPointers(); //everything is ok :)
  var thread = GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();
  handleAppException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception, thread, pointers);
}

private void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  var pointers = Marshal.GetExceptionPointers(); //here IntPtr.Zero :(
  var thread = GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();
  handleAppException(e.Exception as Exception, thread, pointers);
}

private void handleAppException(int threadId, IntPtr pointers)
{
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    MiniDump.CreateMiniDump("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\dump.dmp", threadId, pointers);
  }).Wait();
}
```

If an exception occurs that is associated with another thread, for example:

```
  Thread t = new Thread(() =>
  {
    throw new Exception("Thread exception!");
  });
  t.Start();
```

then `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` and`Marshal.GetExceptionPointers ();`correctly returns a pointer.
And if the exception occurs in the UI thread, for example:

```
throw new Exception("UI thread");
```

then `Current_DispatcherUnhandledException` is executed and`GetExceptionPointers` returns `IntPtr.Zero`.

**Question:**
How do I get `ExceptionPointers` on exception in`UI`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a **solution**:

use `Current.Dispatcher.UnhandledExceptionFilter` instead of `Current.DispatcherUnhandledException`.